# How can I compile and load a new source file in Scala from the REPL?

Tags: scala

In the Scala shell, I would like to be able to load a Scala source file into the current session.  The catch is that I would like that file to be *arbitrary* Scala source code – including, in particular, things such as package declarations.

Is this possible?  If so, how do I do it?

Comment: does this work for you?
http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-how-add-jar-file-scala-repl-classpath-command-line

Comment: Please clarify what does/doesn't work for you when you paste (`:pa filename.scala`) a file into the REPL session.

Comment: @jwnh The REPL barfs on package declarations.

Comment: That's funny. Seems to work for me. What version are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Pass the scala source file ("test.scala" in the snippet below) as an argument to the scala command:

```
scala test.scala
```

This will compile and execute the scala source in the file.

Comment: That doesn't work in my case – the Scala REPL is embedded in Apache Spark.

Comment: Does this mean you are running Spark Shell? Please also provide the version information. Also, clarify what is not working! Is it failing on imports?

Comment: Spark shell CLI just ignores any non-option args.